# Push image to another registry with volume copy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am running an image in a docker container locally with the following commands

```
docker pull locustio/locust
```

and my docker-compose looks as below, for which I use the **docker-compose up**

```
version: '3'

services:
  locust-service:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py -H http://master:8089
```

I have my volume, which is the locustfile.py which has all the code to test my system. Now I would need to push and deploy this image into another private repository along with the volume, that is the file locustfile.py.

How can I do that with the **docker-compose push**? Or is there any other way I can copy the volume? The **docker-compose push** for the above compose file doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Volumes are generally intended to hold *data*, not application code.  You should build your code into a derived Docker image, which then can be pushed.

You can write what you show here into a basic Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM locustio/locust
COPY locustfile.py /mnt/locust
# CMD must be a JSON array if it's passing additional options to an ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["-f", "/mnt/locust/locustfile.py", "-H", "http://master:8089"]
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file only needs to specify to build and run it, but not duplicate any of these options:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  locust-service:
    build: .
    image: my-docker-hub-name/locust
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
```

Then `docker-compose build && docker-compose push` would build and push the image.  On the target host you'd need to copy this `docker-compose.yml` file but remove the `build:` line.

Glancing at the Locust documentation, this is similar to what is suggested to [Use docker image as a base image](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-docker.html#use-docker-image-as-a-base-image).  You also may find it more flexible to [use environment variables](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#environment-variables) to set options, rather than command-line arguments, which would let you split options between the Dockerfile and the `docker-compose.yml` runtime configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Only docker images can be pushed.

The volumes are generated when you run the image creating a container with its volumes as explained in the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ .

I report here the example in the official documentation:

```
docker run -d \
  --name=nginxtest \
  -v nginx-vol:/usr/share/nginx/html \
  nginx:latest
```